# MUI v5 types have no suggestion for code completion in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, material-ui, webstorm

I'm trying to get suggestions for code completion in WebStorm on MUI components and get nothing. What's wrong?

TypeScript v4.4.4
WebStorm 2021.2.3
MUI v5.0.4

[image: WebStorm screenshot]

```
function App() {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <Button variant="contained">a123</Button>
          <Card>123</Card>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in that file here.

Comment: edited topic...

Comment: Where did you import the `Button`?

Comment: `import { Accordion, Button, Card, Tabs } from "@mui/material";`

Comment: upper in the file

Comment: What does it say when you hover the `variant` prop (the error message)? Also is this issue specific to webstorm, can you try other IDE like VSCode?

Comment: i dont have vscode. On hover see added image

Comment: Typescript 4.4.4 was released a [week ago](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases), try downgrading the typescript package. I also see a couple of questions related to typescript lately, may be that's the issue?

Comment: I tried downgrading and got same

Answer (score 3):

Please vote for [WEB-53199](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53199) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: You should post this as a comment because an answer which confirms about a bug can be flagged and removed so OP might not see it.